# Tar a file along with preserved file capabilities

Tags: 20.04, permissions, lubuntu, tar

We are building a root filesystem of Ubuntu 20.04 with packages installed using `debootstrap` and finally tar it using:

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f $ROOTFS --numeric-owner -C $TMPDIR .
```

Eventually, when we untar the root filesystem, the file capabilities are lost. For example, ping loses its `cap_net_raw+ep` capability and this is causing untoward behaviour in production.

I tried passing various tar parameters to preserve the file capabilities but failed to do so. Guidance on this would be of great help.

For very simplistic reproduction:

```
# cd /bin && getcap /bin/ping && rm -f blah.tar && tar --preserve-permissions --xattrs --xattrs-include=*.* -cf ~/blah.tar ping && cd -
/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep
/root

# tar -xf blah.tar && getcap ./ping
#
```

Comment: You need to include xattrs when extracting too

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. What would be minimal set of arguments needed to preserve file capabilities apart from the tar parameters used in: `tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f $ROOTFS --numeric-owner -C $TMPDIR .`